# Update lower/upper bound of range type

Tags: postgresql

I have column of `tstzrange` type (timestamp with time zone range) and I need to update only upper or lower bound of this value (and keep inclusive/exclusive boundaries)

I managed to change

```
(-infinity,infinity)
```

with

```
UPDATE table
SET
    my_column = tstzrange(
        lower(my_column),
        now(),
        '()'
    )
```

and I have

```
(-infinity, <current timestamp>)
```

but I don't know how to keep boundaries from default range.. this would change even `[` `]` to `(` `)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I [found function](https://gist.github.com/karanlyons/3af10ad9a90dbbd02a6b) I missed, it's possible to do that like this

```
UPDATE table
SET
    my_column = tstzrange(
        lower(my_column),
        now(),
        concat(
            CASE WHEN lower_inc(my_column) THEN '[' ELSE '(' END,
            CASE WHEN upper_inc(my_column) THEN ']' ELSE ')' END
        )
    )
```

It would be better to create function for this probably. Or is there any other (simpler/better) solution?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, using CASE WHEN... is the best way to get the bounds.  Here are some simple user-defined functions that return the range bounds for all the native range types.

**Warning:** These functions behave in surprising ways, because the range types behave in [sometimes surprising ways](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/rangetypes.html).

> The built-in range types **int4range, int8range, and daterange** all use a
>   canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper
>   bound; that is, [).

And

> Although '(]' is specified here, **on display the value will be
>   converted to canonical form**, since int8range is a discrete range type . . .

(emphasis added)

PostgreSQL canonicalizes the closed range from 1 to 10 as a half open range from 1 to 11.

```
select int4range('[1,10]');
[1,11)
```

It does the same thing for ranges that are half open on the left.

```
select int4range('(1,10]');
[2,11)
```

range_bounds() returns the bounds for result, not for the input.

```
select range_bounds(int4range('(1,10]'));
[)
```

**The functions**

```
create or replace function range_bounds(in range int4range)
returns char(2) as 
$$
select case when lower_inc(range) then '[' else '(' end ||
       case when upper_inc(range) then ']' else ')' end;
$$
language sql
returns null on null input;

create or replace function range_bounds(in range int8range)
returns char(2) as 
$$
select case when lower_inc(range) then '[' else '(' end ||
       case when upper_inc(range) then ']' else ')' end;
$$
language sql
returns null on null input;

create or replace function range_bounds(in range numrange)
returns char(2) as 
$$
select case when lower_inc(range) then '[' else '(' end ||
       case when upper_inc(range) then ']' else ')' end;
$$
language sql
returns null on null input;


create or replace function range_bounds(in range tsrange)
returns char(2) as 
$$
select case when lower_inc(range) then '[' else '(' end ||
       case when upper_inc(range) then ']' else ')' end;
$$
language sql
returns null on null input;

create or replace function range_bounds(in range tstzrange)
returns char(2) as 
$$
select case when lower_inc(range) then '[' else '(' end ||
       case when upper_inc(range) then ']' else ')' end;
$$
language sql
returns null on null input;

create or replace function range_bounds(in range daterange)
returns char(2) as 
$$
select case when lower_inc(range) then '[' else '(' end ||
       case when upper_inc(range) then ']' else ')' end;
$$
language sql
returns null on null input;
```

Answer (score 1):

Improvement to Mikes [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18161969/1041641).

When we use the pseudo-type [anyrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-pseudo.html), we only need a single function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION range_bounds(IN range anyrange)
    RETURNS CHAR(2) AS
$$
SELECT CASE WHEN lower_inc(range) THEN '[' ELSE '(' END ||
       CASE WHEN upper_inc(range) THEN ']' ELSE ')' END;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```