# What are the benefits of using Postgresql Daterange type instead of two Date fields?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.4 and I discovered today the `Daterange` type. Until now I used a field *startDateTime* and an other field *startEndTime*, so what would be the benefits  of using the `Daterange` type instead?

Comment: Exclusion constraints: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing that you can't do with a `startDateTime` and an `endDateTime` that you can do with a `tsrange` (or `daterange` for `date`s). However, there a quite a few [operators on range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) that make writing queries far more concise and understandable. Operators like overlap `&&`, containment `@>` and adjacency `-|-` between two ranges are especially useful for date and time ranges. A big bonus for range types is that you apply a [`gist` index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING) on them which makes searches much faster.

As an example, find all rows where an `event` takes place within a certain time range:

**Start/end**

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE startDateTime >= '2016-01-01'::timestamp
  AND endDateTime < '2016-01-19'::timestamp;
```

**Range**

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE startEndRange <@ tsrange('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-01-19'::timestamp);
```

Comment: Somewhat misleading first sentence: you start by saying that you can do everything with to separate date columns, but end by saying that you can't use gist with it. Is the ability to use gist not relevant when writing that first sentence? Is performance not an important factor in database design, and not only a "bonus"?

Answer (score 9):

Some additions to [Patricks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34891628/1041641):

- Information if the lower/upper bound is included or excluded

  - the range type explicitly includes this information and it can be different per row
- `NULL`

  - When we have 2 separate cols, we can define nullable for each of them.
  - When using a single tsrange column, we can use a check constraint: [PostgreSQL 9.2 tstzrange null/infinity CONSTRAINT CHECK](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51602/164398)
- Cannot get date from empty `tsrange`

  - `select lower(tsrange('2020-12-01', '2020-12-01'));` returns `NULL`
  - this was a gotcha for me: I don't know if it's possible to get the start/end date
- updating

  - When you have 2 date-time fields, you can update each one separately
  - for tsrange you must create a new value and consider the boundaries: see [Update lower/upper bound of range type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145852/update-lower-upper-bound-of-range-type)
- tsrange will throw an error when the start is lower than the end

  ```sql
  select tsrange('2020-12-20', '2020-12-19'); 
  -- [22000] ERROR: range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound
  ```
- keep in mind, that the range types may not be supported by some drivers/libraries/tools. e.g. [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) have no build-in support. But there are external packages to add support, e.g. [node-pg-range](https://github.com/WhoopInc/node-pg-range)

Comment: Actually, in [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), range can be supported with just one extra line of code, using [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting), to define the range that you want.

Comment: @vitaly-t can you elaborate? I.e. do you mean one line to register the node-pg-range type?

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. I meant exactly what I wrote - implement your own range converter, using `Custom Type Formatting`, which provides a very simple syntax. Can't really go into further detail inside comments :)

Comment: Ok, here's a simple example: `const tsrange = (start, end) => ({rawType: true, toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('tsrange($1, $2)', [start, end])});`. Then, for the query formatting value you can pass in `tsrange(start, end)`, and it will be formatted correctly. So it takes one line to implement one type of range formatting.

Comment: That's only for writing to postgres and the bounds handling is missing (open/closed). Also empty ranges cannot easily be supported with such a simple function. And reading back `tsrange` from postgres is not handled at all with this single-line: i.e. pg-promise will only return a string. So to get a real class-instance back, we need to register a [type-parser](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types#use)

Comment: Anyway, I agree that it's easy to support `tsrange` in pg-promise. But it's a fact, that there is no built-in support. And that is something to keep in mind when you decide to use `tsrange` or two date-fields.